# Probability of orbital angular momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, wavefunction, hilbert-space

I've attached a question that I've been stuck on for a while. Can anyone tell me how to answer it?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: You need to write angular momentum operator in position representation and  hit it to Y than you should find how much X in that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two ways to answer this question. For fun I will answer it in 2 ways. First note that the answer is

$$
P=|\langle X_{1,1} | Y_{1,1} \rangle|^2 
$$

If you don't follow this then you should go back to the axioms of quantum mechanics and understand why. Below I assume you know said axioms and are just having trouble with converting them to an answer.

**First Solution**

This is a straightforward integral and I am not quite sure what trouble you are having with it.

$$
\langle X_{1,1} | Y_{1,1} \rangle= \frac{3}{8 \pi} \int d\Omega_2 \sin \theta e^{i \phi} (\sin\theta \sin \phi + \cos\theta) = \frac{i}{2}
$$

So we get

$$
P=\frac{1}{4}
$$

**Second Solution**

A much more enlightening and simpler one is the following if you understand what is going on. You are looking at a 3 dimensional Hilbert space and the angular momentum operators for 3-dimensions can be written as

$$
\begin{align}
  J_x &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
    \begin{pmatrix}
      0 &1 &0\\
      1 &0 &1\\
      0 &1 &0
    \end{pmatrix} \\
  J_y &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
    \begin{pmatrix}
      0 &-i &0\\
      i &0  &-i\\
      0 &i  &0
    \end{pmatrix} \\
  J_z &=
    \begin{pmatrix}
      1 &0 &0\\
      0 &0 &0\\
      0 &0 &-1
   \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

In particular, in this basis, the state

$$
|Y_{1,1} \rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$

and

$$
|X_{1,1} \rangle = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix}
$$

as can be easily verified. From this you straighforwardly get the probability as the square of overlap

$$
P=|\langle X_{1,1} | Y_{1,1} \rangle|^2 = \frac{1}{4}
$$

Note that by symmetry and conservation of angular momentum you can get the probability to be found in other states as well.

**Connection between the two solutions**

We want to evaluate

$$
\langle X_{1,1} | Y_{1,1} \rangle
$$

and if we know them in a basis in the 3-dimensional Hilbert space (as in the second solution above) we can directly get the answer. We are however free to insert a complete set of states and this complete set can be from a bigger Hilbert state. In particular if we take the infinite dimensional Hilbert space of the angular variables we can write

$$
\langle X_{1,1} | Y_{1,1} \rangle = \int d\Omega_2 
\langle X_{1,1} | \theta,\phi\rangle \langle \theta,\phi| Y_{1,1} \rangle
$$

where $d\Omega_2$ is the differential element on the 2-sphere and this is what the first method is doing.

Comment: In my course we have only just touched upon Dirac notation so some of this looks quite alien to me. Would I be correct in saying that P=|⟨X1,1|Y1,1⟩|^2 is the probability density at X1,1?

Comment: You would not be for multiple reasons. First note the Hilbert space is 3 dimensional and not infinite so there is no notion of probability density. Second, the expression you wrote IS the probability of state $X_{1,1}$ being found in state $Y_{1,1}$. Third point is that you could map the finite dimensional Hilbert space to the inifinite dimensional one and that is what is commonly called the wavefunction (as opposed to the state).

Comment: So $\langle \theta,\phi | Y_{1,1}\rangle
 = -\sqrt{\frac{3}{8\pi}}\sin \theta e^{i\phi}$. So what the first method is doing is actually putting a sum over states. I am editing the my answer to explain that.

Comment: When I put your integral  for the first solution in wolfram alpha it comes out as 3ipi/16 not 1/2i?

Comment: What are you using Mathematica for when its such a simple integration? It's good your question is on hold. You seem not to be doing any work on your own. My answer was only off by a minus sign which I was not careful about as it doesn't matter for probability. If you cannot do integrals by hand then at least learn to use Mathematica properly.

Comment: you missed out the extra sin(theta) that is necessary when you integrate in spherical coordinates, which is why my calculation by hand was wrong and why the wolfram alpha calculation was wrong. Maybe you should learn how to integrate in spherical coordinates properly

Comment: I have it at the bottom where I write the connection between the two. The measure on the 2-sphere includes the $\sin(\theta)$. It is surprising you cannot tell the difference between a typo and the inability to do spherical integrals. If you see the wrong measure in an integral you should assume its a typo before plugging it into mathematica. Anyways, I am correcting it. Thanks for pointing it out.